# Sum of digits at Even and Odd Places in C

Tags: c

I need to add the digits on the even and odd places in an integer. Say, Let number = 1234567. Sum of even place digits = 2+4+6 = 12 Sum of odd place digits = 1+3+5+7 = 16

The code I currently have is:

```
int returnsum(int num) {
  while (num) {
    rem = num % 10;
    sum = sum + rem;
    num = num / 10;
  }
  while (sum) {
    a = sum % 10;
    arr[i] = a:
      sum = sum / 10;
    i++;
  }
  for (i = 0; a[i]; i += 2) {
    summ = summ + a[i];
  }
  return summ;
}

void main() {
  int n, m, oddSum = 0, evenSum = 0;
  printf("Please insert the number for the program:");
  scanf("%d", & n);
  while (n != 0) {
    oddSum += n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    evenSum += n % 10;
    n /= 10;
  }
  printf("Sum of digits in even  places:%d\n", evenSum);
  printf("Sum of digits in odd  places:%d\n", oddSum);
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: I have reversed the number and put it in array and elements at odd or even places but it too long.

Comment: what reverse is going to do here?

Comment: @almasshaikh I think by reverse (s)he meant `%` and `/` to take out each digit. That will automatically reverse. :-)

Comment: int returnsum(int num)
{

while(num)
{
rem=num%10;
sum=sum+rem;
num=num/10);
}
while(sum)
{
a=sum%10;
arr[i]=a:
sum=sum/10;
i++;
}
for(i=0;a[i];i+=2)
{
summ=summ+a[i];
}
return summ;
}

Comment: Please edit your post and add the code there. As it is currently written ,  I am not able to find a definition of `rem`, `sum` or `summ`, `a[i]` etc.

Comment: I've added your code from the comment, it's been so long since I was at rep 1, I can't even remember if you're allowed to edit your questions :-)

Comment: @sorav see ans i have posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem:

```
void main()
{
 int n,m,oddSum=0,evenSum=0;
 printf("Please insert the number for the program:");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 int flag=0;
 int counter=1;
 while (n!=0) {
   if(counter%2==0)
   {
     evenSum += n % 10;
     n /= 10;
   }
   else
   {
     oddSum += n % 10;
     n /= 10;
   }
   counter++;
 }

 if(counter%2==0)
 {
   int temp=oddSum;
   oddSum=evenSum;
   evenSum=temp;
 }
 printf("Sum of digits in even  places:%d\n",evenSum);
 printf("Sum of digits in odd  places:%d\n",oddSum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's first assume the number has an *even* number of digits, so that the second-last and last are at odd and even positions respectively.

Then, the last digit can be retrieved with `number % 10` and the second last with `(number / 10) % 10`.

So, knowing that, you can simply loop over the number, adding those values and dividing by a hundred until you get a number less than ten.

If that number is zero, then your assumption about the original having an even number of digits was correct and you can exit.

If it's a non-zero (`1..9`), then your assumption was wrong, you should swap the even and odd sums to date then add the final digit to the odd sum.

The pseudo-code goes something like this:

```
def getEvenOdd (num):
    even = 0
    odd = 0

    while num > 9:
        even = even + (num % 10)
        odd = odd + ((num / 10) % 10)
        num = num / 100

    if num > 0:
        temp = even
        even = odd
        odd = temp
        odd = odd +  num

    return (even,odd)

print getEvenOdd(1234567)
```

And the output of that would be something like `(12,16)`.

---

And it's no accident that pseudo-code looks like beginner's Python, since that language is the perfect pseudo-code language, provided you don't mess about with the more complex corners of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
char p[20];
int i=0,even=0,odd=0,n;
scanf("%d",&n);
sprintf(p,"%d",n);
while(p[i] != '\0')
{
    if(i%2 == 0)
    odd+= (p[i] - '0');
    else
    even+= (p[i] - '0');

    i++;
}
printf("%d\n",even);
printf("%d\n",odd);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My five cents.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct pair
{
    unsigned int odd;
    unsigned int even;
} pair_t;   

pair_t GetSums( unsigned int x )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;
    pair_t sums = { 0u, 0u };
    size_t n = 0;

    do
    {
        if ( ++n & 1 ) sums.odd += x % Base;
        else sums.even += x % Base;
    } while ( x /= Base );

    if ( ( n & 1 )  == 0 )
    {
        unsigned int tmp = sums.odd;
        sums.odd = sums.even;
        sums.even = tmp; 
    }

    return sums;
}

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        unsigned int x;
        pair_t sums;

        printf( "\nEnter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );
        if ( scanf( "%u", &x ) != 1 || x == 0 ) break;

        sums = GetSums( x );

        printf( "\nSum of digits in odd  positions is %u\n", sums.odd );            
        printf( "Sum of digits in even positions is %u\n", sums.even );         

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1234567

Sum of digits in odd  positions is 16
Sum of digits in even positions is 12

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 123456

Sum of digits in odd  positions is 9
Sum of digits in even positions is 12

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum every other digit, simply divide by 100 in each iteration:

```
int sumodd(int num) {
    int sum = 0, rem;
    while(num) {
        rem=num%10;
        sum=sum+rem;
        num=num/100);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Since we already have a function that can sum every other digit, we can re-use it:

```
int sumeven(int num) {
    return sumodd(num/10);
}
```